# Why did i get this "module 'nltk.translate.metrics' has no attribute 'precision'"?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nltk, metrics, naivebayes

import codes, i've tried importing precision and all the library i still can't get it work

```
import nltk
import string
import pandas as pd
import nltk.metrics
import collections

from nltk import precision
from nltk.metrics.scores import (accuracy, precision, recall, f_measure,log_likelihood, approxrand)
from nltk import precision
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import classify
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import NaiveBayesClassifier
from random import shuffle
from nltk.metrics.scores import (precision, recall)
```

the codes below are the codes i use to implement the codes

```
path = os.path.join('c:' + os.sep, 'Users', 'User', 'Documents', 'Reviews_Labeled.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(path)

positive = []
negative = []
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    if df.iloc[i][1] == 'Positive':
        positive.append(df.iloc[i][0])
    else:
        negative.append(df.iloc[i][0])

positive_tokens = []
for i in positive:
    positive_tokens.append(word_tokenize(i))

negative_tokens = []
for i in negative:
    negative_tokens.append(word_tokenize(i))

def is_clean(word: str):
    if word in string.punctuation:
        return False
    if word.isnumeric():
        return False
    if word in stopwords.words('english'):
        return False
    return True

def clean_tokens(tokens: list):
    return [word.lower() for word in tokens if is_clean(word)]

positive_tokens_cleaned = [clean_tokens(tokens) for tokens in positive_tokens]
negative_tokens_cleaned = [clean_tokens(tokens) for tokens in negative_tokens]

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemmatize(word: str, tag: str):
    if tag.startswith('NN'):
        pos = 'n'
    elif tag.startswith('VB'):
        pos = 'v'
    else:
        pos = 'a'
    return lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, pos)

def lemmatize_tokens(tokens: list):
    return [lemmatize(word, tag) for word, tag in pos_tag(tokens)]

positive_tokens_normalized = [lemmatize_tokens(tokens) for tokens in positive_tokens_cleaned]
negative_tokens_normalized = [lemmatize_tokens(tokens) for tokens in negative_tokens_cleaned]

dataset = positive_dataset + negative_dataset

shuffle(dataset)

train_ds = dataset[:5126]
test_ds = dataset[5126:]

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_ds)
classify.accuracy(classifier, test_ds)
```

when i'm searching other people question this is the way people call out the precision value and other metrics value

```
refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)

for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(test_ds):
    refsets[label].add(i)
    observed = classifier.classify(feats)
    testsets[observed].add(i)
```

this is the code i use to try and print the precision value

```
print(nltk.metrics.scores.precision(refsets['pos'],testsets['pos']))
```

this is the error i got

[image]

```
print(nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'],testsets['pos']))
```

this also give the same error

so how do i solve the error message what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue as you, and here's my solution:

```
print(nltk.precision(refsets['pos'],testsets['pos']))
```

I noticed that the error was the attribute error, showing that it is trying to access to the **ntlk.translate.metrics** which certainly do not have the precision function you want.
Instead, the precision function that you wanted is located in at the **ntlk.metrics.score.**
Which both of the module serves a very different purpose.

My guess is the compiler is just having hard time finding the **ntlk.metrics.score** module with the calling you did.

You can refer to the ntlk documentation for more detail implementation of the ntlk.metrics.score
https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.scores.html

Answer (score 0):

nltk.scores.precision also should work.